# LaTeX equations do not render in google Colaboratory when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, google-colaboratory

If I take the official example containing latex from the [matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html):

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Example data
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{time} (s)')
plt.ylabel(r'\textit{voltage} (mV)',fontsize=16)
plt.title(r"\TeX\ is Number "
          r"$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
          fontsize=16, color='gray')
# Make room for the ridiculously large title.
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

plt.savefig('tex_demo')
plt.show()
```

and try to run it in a Google Colab notebook it will produce a big stacktrace with the following message at the end:

```
 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex': 'latex'
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix that?

**My attempts:**
I thought this error might happen because latex is missing in the serving VM so I tried to install texlive before importing matplotlib with:

```
! sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

This finishes successfully. However matplotlib complains about some missing latex *.sty file which after googling should be contained in the `texlive-latex-extra` package. But during the installation of the extra package  some errors occurred:

```
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ruby2.5 amd64 2.5.1-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 texlive-latex-extra all 2017.20180305-2 [10.6 MB]
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libruby2.5 amd64 2.5.1-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 texlive-plain-generic all 2017.20180305-2 [23.6 MB]
Fetched 41.5 MB in 4s (11.3 MB/s)
```

So I cant finish the installation of `texlive-latex-extra`. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually there is an easier solution, that requires less passages with respect to the answer proposed by @v.tralala. It's indeed enough to install the ubuntu packages containing the required .sty files, that in this case are `texlive-latex-extra` and `dvipng`. So do the following installations:

```
!sudo apt install cm-super dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended
```

To find an ubuntu package that contains a specific .sty file see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39771/finding-a-ubuntu-package-for-a-sty-file

Comment: This almost worked, I also had to add `! sudo apt install cm-super` to avoid being told I was missing type1ec.sty

Comment: Thank you, this was also pointed out in the answer of Iman, maybe something has changed during this period.

Answer (score 7):

### The Cause

Basically, the problem is that `type1cm` and `type1em` is not installed by default with matplotlib in colab environment. More on this issue here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17412

### Solution

```
!apt install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra cm-super dvipng
```

The `type1cm` is part of `texlive-fonts-extra` and `type1ec` is a part of `cm-super`.

So to setup latex in matplotlib, you should have this block in your colab notebook:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
!apt install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra cm-super dvipng
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work anymore. The `rcParams` line causes an error, and the apt-get install also fails with a 404.

Answer (score 2):

So this a very hacky solution, but I got it to work atleast. The problem was indeed the missing texlive package. After installing `texlive-latex-recommended` one still needs a `type1cm.sty` file for the matplotlib example to work. Since the extra package could not be installed easily, I manually installed the type1cm package. To achieve this I executed following commands before importing matplotlib:

```
! sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended #1
! sudo apt-get install dvipng texlive-fonts-recommended #2
! wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/type1cm.zip #3
! unzip type1cm.zip -d /tmp/type1cm #4
! cd /tmp/type1cm/type1cm/ && sudo latex type1cm.ins  #5
! sudo mkdir /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/type1cm #6
! sudo cp /tmp/type1cm/type1cm/type1cm.sty /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/type1cm #7
! sudo texhash #8
```

Those commands will do the following:

1. minimal texlive installation which still works
2. not sure if those packages are necessary, but wont hurt to much
3. download `type1cm` package from ctan offically
4. unzip to /tmp/type1cm
5. install package by running `latex` command on `type1cm.ins` file. Note that providing the path directly to the latex command didnt work. Also the `cd` and `latex` command have to be executed in the same line( behind the the same ! symbol), otherwise the cd has no effect
6. create folder for type1cm packge in texmf tree
7. copy .sty file there
8. update tex so that it find the new package

**Resources**:
[How to install type1cm](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/type1cm/type1cm-doc.pdf)
[Where to place *.sty files in Linux texlive install](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142953/81783)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with:

```
sudo apt-get install cm-super dvipng
```