# How to Plot a Table of Pandas DataFrame using Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to plot a table of Pandas DataFrame using Matplolib tight_layout() in Colab.

First, LaTex was not found while running my code in Colab. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746749/latex-equations-do-not-render-in-google-colaboratory-when-using-matplotlib) but then I got an `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` error. I get the same error in Jupyter-Lab too but in the terminal, it works!

How can I make this code work in Colab?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['P(S)'] = [0.4, 0.3]
df['P(F)'] = [0.2, 0.1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in get_default_bbox_extra_artists(self)
   2234                 bbox_artists.extend(ax.get_default_bbox_extra_artists())
   2235         # we don't want the figure's patch to influence the bbox calculation
-> 2236         bbox_artists.remove(self.patch)
   2237         return bbox_artists
   2238 

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: This might be due to different versions of matplotlib in use. But it might also be due to specific jupyter/colab settings. Chances are higher for someone to find out more about the problem if you indicate all versions in use.